# Kotlin database update function returning 0 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, kotlin

Below is a function I have created that is supposed to update a row in a database.

```
fun editQuestion(identifier: String, questionNumber: Int, questionText: String, answers: Array<String>, correctAns: Int) {
        val db = this.writableDatabase

        val contentValues = ContentValues()
        contentValues.put(QUESTION_TEXT, questionText)
        for (i in answers.indices) {
            contentValues.put(ANSWER_ARRAY[i], answers[i])
        }
        contentValues.put(CORRECT_ANS, correctAns)

        db.update(QUESTION_TABLE, contentValues, "$MASTER_ID = ? AND $QUESTION_NUM = $questionNumber", arrayOf(identifier))
    }
```

After the function is called, the database data does not seemed to have changed and when printing the output of `db.update()`, it returns `0`.

I have similar functions that update other tables in the database successfully so `db.update()` does work.

I also have functions that have `db.update()` calls that target the table in the above function so the table can be manipulated.

I have also double checked if the parameters for this function and the values are what they should be.

I also know the `WHERE` clause is correct as I use the exact same one to delete a row in the same table.

And finally, I also checked whether I was making correct use of `val contentValues` and it seems to be correct.

So my question really is what am I missing? I can't think of what else could be happening. Any help would be appreciated and just ask if more code or context is needed to answer.

Comment: `db.update()` does not return `false` or `true`. It returns the number of the updated rows in the table.

Comment: @forpas oh I see, i assumed the the 0 meant false

Comment: If you get 0 then this means that no row was updated, probably because there is no row under the conditions in the WHERE caluse.

Comment: @forpas yep, that helped me solve it. Thx

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having similar issues, really do check your parameters!

My `questionNumber` parameter was 1 less than it should be here and it solved my issue. In short, it was a PICNIC issue.